# How can you calculate the number of possible combinations of a set based on rules about repetition?

Tags: statistics, combinations

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the number of unique combinations of certain letters and numbers, while ensuring that there are never more than X letters in a row.

Essentially we have a set of L letters (26 or less). Then we have a set of N numbers (10 or less). I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the number of ways these sets can combined into strings of length S.

All of these are changeable, because I'm trying to figure out the best combination of them.

Some examples:

How many combinations of 10 letters and numbers (36 total characters) are there that contain no more than 2 letters in a row? So 1111AA2AA3 is valid, but ABC12A23A4 is invalid.

How many combinations are there when you allow up to 3 letters in a row? So 1111AAA2AA is valid but ABCD1AB1AB is invalid.

This is for a password generator thing, so I'm trying to figure out how tweaking these dials increases entropy, and therefore how you'd actually go about calculating this, not really what any specific answer for one example is.

Comment: Many unanswered questions here. How long are the strings; what does 'various lengths' mean? English alphabet with 26 letters, digits 0 through 9? Letters and digits chosen at random with replacement--out of 36 possibilities for each position? If random, then what do you mean by 'left out for various reasons'? You will have better success here if you specify a _particular_ problem and give the exact rules. Consider the method of solution. Then generalize the problem a bit if necessary. Impossibly vague as it stands. You may want to read material on 'distribution of runs'.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to add more details. I'm not looking for a specific answer, more how you'd actually calculate it based on these factors.

Comment: Suggest you edit your Question with one or two (at most) very specific well-considered problems of the type you have in mind. Look at answers and generalize from there. I see you have a few votes to re-open already. So editing your question in this way is likely not a waste of time and effort.

Comment: I added 2, will those work?

Comment: Evidently so. We'll see if you get helpful answers.